# How can I set the orientation that apps launch in from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad. I have a Smart Cover. I have Xcode 7.2.

I am developing an app that is set to allow Landscape Left and Landscape Right orientations.

I have my iPad on the desk propped up by the smart cover with the home button on the left side of the device. I have the iPad unlocked, on the home screen, and everything looks great.

When I build and run my app from Xcode, it decides to run in the opposite orientation, so everything is upside down.

This makes no sense. How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: does the same happen if you start the app on the device itself rather than through xcode?

Comment: hmm, actually, the splash screen shows in the correct orientation. then the app appears upside down briefly, then rights itself.